# Why are images not getting served on starting production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, production-environment, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.1.0 application on a live server which when started in development mode serves all images and favicon.ico nicely.

But when the same app is started in production environment, the favicon image/other images in public folder are not served and their paths throws a 404 error (Interestingly, the static images of the 404 page are also not served). Any clue Rails Gods?

I am using NginX + Unicorn + Rails 3.1.0. Assets pipeline is used for everything except for 404/500 error pages and favicon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to show the files in my public folder in production mode too. I set "**config.serve_static_assets**" to **true** in "**config/environments/production.rb**", and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving all your images to `app/assets/images` instead? That is where the asset pipeline in Rails 3.1 serves images from. (For example, in a fresh 3.1.0 app, the `rails.png` file is now in `app/assets/images` instead of 'public/images').

Comment: Doing that will fail the purpose of having a 404/500 error pages, isn't it? If the server dies out, the images inside app/assets/images will not be served on pages that handle errors. Isn't it weird that images couldn't be served from a public folder - specifically in production mode?

Comment: Interestingly, the favicon has now popped up from public folder but images of 404 (error pages) have not! Here: http://bubbleideas.com/404

Comment: You're supposed to put images in app/assets/images, but you have to run bundle exec rake assets:precompile each time you deploy so that it copies them to public/assets where your webserver can actually find them. The main reason to bother with the precompile step is for asset-digests.

Comment: Do remember to use the helper methods to access the javascript, stylesheets and images (in Rails code and CSS). Hard-coding these links won't work in production because asset fingerprinting is used.

Answer (score 0):

FYI; if you're pulling up CSS background images, then you need to put in 'assets/imagename.jpg' instead of the old route of even just 'imagename.jpg'